# Invoke function of injected element of Chrome Extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have been trying to call a function of a button element that I injected using `content_scripts` . Here is my `manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test2",
  "description": "my test exention",
  "version": "1.0",
  "author": "xyz",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "jquery-3.3.1.min.js",
        "inject.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "main.html",
    "default_title": "My custom google Extension"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "webNavigation"
  ]
}
```

And here is my `inject.js`

```
window.addEventListener("load", myMain, false);

function myMain(evt) {
    $('body').append('<div> <button id="download-btn">hello</button> </div>');  
}
```

Other files (`background.js`, `main.html`) are empty. I can add a button in any web page using this code, but I want to execute a function ( for example a simple `console.log`) by clicking the button. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Use standard jQuery: add `.find('button').on('click', onClick)` after the last `)` and declare onClick function.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks, I did it in a slightly different way `button.onclick = function () { myFunction()}` and then append the `button` in `body`